# listeners on DataView in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I got a problem with a `Dataview`. The `Dataview` should have a listeners on the items it renders.

so here is how my `Dataview` looks like:

```
var childrenData = Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
    store: {
        fields: ['id', 'name', 'children'],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/category/view',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true,
    },
    itemTpl: childrenTemplate,
    listeners: {
             itemtap: function(data,index){
                    var record = data.getStore().getAt(index);
                console.log(record);
          }
    }
});
```

Has anybody, any Idea why this doesn't work?

Edit: added Template data:
    var childrenTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate('',
                        '',
                            '',
                                    '{name}',
                                '',
                            '',
                                '',
                                    ' {price}',
                                '',
                            '',
                        '',
                     ''
    );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the Problem was.

The dataview was in a Container that was in a TabPanel.

After some trial and error, I found out that if I define the Container as an configuration object with
    xtype: 'container'
it works. If I create the Container over 
    Ext.create('Ext.Container', {});
 it somehow doesn't work.
Already asked in Sencha Forum if its a Bug or a Feature, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: did the folks at sencha get back to you on this ? definitely seems like a bug. any way you can post your code for this that fixes the issue. I am having the same problems... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code; (for sencha-touch-2)

```
var childrenData = Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
        store: {
            fields: ['id', 'name', 'children'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/category/view',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true,
        },
        itemTpl: childrenTemplate
    });
```

add listener with;

```
childrenData.on({
      tap: function(data,index){
              var record = data.getStore().getAt(index);
              console.log(record);
         }
});
```

Comment: I worked a lot on it last night, and the listener is bound correctly.
childrenData.hastlisteners returns true, I have the feeling its because of the template.
The generated HTML, has only one x-dataview-item, but many nested divs, with the rendered Template. I wonder why it just starts one dataview. template data is: